# How do I add the watermark image with different positions in PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading, watermark

Hi I want to add **watermark image** with different positions like

`top-left`,
`top-right`,
`bottom-left`,
`bottom-right`,
`center`.

Admin select one of the above position in the `setting` tab. I am using the `Orakuploader` plugin and in that plugin the watermark occur is in the **center** of the uploaded image.

Here is the code of **watermark image** for **`center`** position:

```
function addWatermark($watermark, $imageDirectory, $imageName, $x = 0, $y = 0)
{
    if(file_exists($watermark))
    {
        $marge_right  = 0;
        $marge_bottom = 0;

        $stamp = imagecreatefrompng($watermark);

        $image_extension = @end(explode(".", $imageName));
        switch($image_extension)
        {
            case "jpg":
                $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("$imageDirectory/$imageName");
                break;
            case "jpeg":
                $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("$imageDirectory/$imageName");
                break;
            case "png":
                $im = imagecreatefrompng("$imageDirectory/$imageName");
                break;
        }

        $imageSize = getimagesize("$imageDirectory/$imageName");
        $watermark_o_width = imagesx($stamp);
        $watermark_o_height = imagesy($stamp);

        $newWatermarkWidth = $imageSize[0];
        $newWatermarkHeight = $watermark_o_height * $newWatermarkWidth / $watermark_o_width;


        if((int)$x <= 0)
            $x = $imageSize[0]/2 - $newWatermarkWidth/2;
        if((int)$y <= 0)
            $y = $imageSize[1]/2 - $newWatermarkHeight/2;

        imagecopyresized($im, $stamp, $x, $y, 0, 0, $newWatermarkWidth, $newWatermarkHeight, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

        switch($image_extension)
        {
            case "jpg":
                header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
                imagejpeg($im, "$imageDirectory/$imageName", 100);
                break;
            case "jpeg":
                header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
                imagejpeg($im, "$imageDirectory/$imageName", 100);
                break;
            case "png":
                header('Content-type: image/png');
                imagepng($im, "$imageDirectory/$imageName");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

How to add watermark with rest of the positions like (`top-left`, `top-right`, `bottom-left` and `bottom-right`)?

Much appreciated for your help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey Dude try by replace this **code** with `imagecopyresized`  function.
I hope it can work for you.
Thanks.

```
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// top-left
imagecopy($im, $stamp, -45, -5, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// top-right
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx + 45, -5, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// bottom-left
imagecopy($im, $stamp, -45, imagesy($im) - $sy + 5, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// bottom-right
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx + 45, imagesy($im) - $sy + 5, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// center
imagecopy($im, $stamp, (imagesx($im) - $sx)/2, (imagesy($im) - $sy)/2, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use Intervention Image library for this purpose. It has a robust and expressive API

For watermarking with different positioning, you can refer to this page

http://image.intervention.io/api/insert

You should end up with something like this

```
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');
$watermark = Image::make('public/watermark.png');
$img->insert('public/watermark.png', 'bottom-right', 10, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I paid the `Orakuploader` library for much more functionality like sorting, cropping, rotating, uploading, watermarking etc. So I want to help for watermarking the images with different positions within that library.

Comment: Why not use both? (e.g. Intervention/image for watermark and Orakuploader for other tasks). To be honest Intervention/image can do it all... it's the best I've came across.